# My Header Div is not working

Tags: html, css, header

My header doesn't work, as in when I give it a

```
background: #XXXXXX
```

it doesn't fill the whole header just 2 sides and when I add a width of say 90% and margin of 0 auto the colour disappears completely.

```
body{
 font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, Helvetica;
 font-size:15px;
line-height:1.5;
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-color:#0a1612

}
/* Global */
.container{
width:80%;
margin:auto;
overflow:hidden;
background:#c5c1c0

}
/* Header */
header {
 background:#f7ce3e
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;

  }
```

Comment: can you please post your code

Comment: Please could you provide some code, which you have tried

Comment: Please include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have now......

Answer (score 1):

In header section after `background:#f7ce3e` **;** semicolon is missing. that's why all the styles that goes after it isn't being applyed.
Here is fixed example.

```css
body{
font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, Helvetica;
font-size:15px;
line-height:1.5;
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-color:#0a1612;

}
/* Global */
.container{
width:80%;
margin:auto;
overflow:hidden;
background:#c5c1c0;
}
/* Header */
header {
 background:#f7ce3e;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 5%;
  }
```

```html
<header> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Repudiandae consectetur voluptas reiciendis officiis nisi, eius recusandae odio voluptatum quod modi aliquid iste distinctio accusamus placeat maiores quam possimus! Eius, animi. </header>
<div class="container">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis iste quam unde omnis ex debitis assumenda atque, quae voluptatibus temporibus. Ratione perspiciatis incidunt fuga laudantium magnam tempora eligendi nesciunt quis.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you fixed that problem but still is the header color only showing up on each side and not covering the full header

Comment: You can add `padding: 0 5%;` to header in order to fill the space 100% -  90%-is given to width, 5%-from right and 5% from left: I will update the above code with this